# Detecting dGPU drivers in Ubuntu on Surface Book

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I have a W10 Surface Book which has the new(ish) native support for Ubuntu16.04. I'm trying to get Tensorflow to work, I've installed cuda and cudnn correctly and they both appear to be working. Tensorflow/python are also correctly setup. The problem I am having now is getting Ubuntu to recognize the NVIDIA dGPU in the performance base.

According to my device manager, W10 is detecting it, but when I try `nvidia-sim` in Ubuntu it says it cannot communicate with the drivers. I also try `echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICE` and there are none. When I check the drivers using `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` this is what I get:

```
ii  nvidia-384                            384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 384.90
ii  nvidia-384-dev                        384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-modprobe                       384.81-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-384                 384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                          0.8.2                                      amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                       384.90-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                 amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

I thought maybe a path issue, but I've set my paths as suggested in the install instructions:

```
#cuda
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64\
                         ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}"
```

At this point I've tried reinstalling/purging everything multiple times all day, but I just cannot get this to work.

Does anybody have any ideas for what I can do?

Comment: The Surface Book GPU is apparently some kind of custom Nvidia GPU - perhaps built just for Microsoft. As such it is up to Nvidia to publish drivers for it for Linux and they appear to have not done that. FWIW it is apparently similar to a Nvidia 940M, but I couldn't get it to be recognized by installing drivers that apparently support the 940M even I have no trouble using the same GPU in Windows with Cuda. 
It is a shame.

Comment: thing is a good deal more complex, have a look at [this](https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface) kernel and issues there, there's a long discussion on how to solve the dGPU base.